# Is it possible to make a curve line when you hover something?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a curve line hover in CSS when you hover something

```css
      <style>
          
          .Exp{
          font-size:50px;
          text-align:center;
          }
          
          .Exp:hover {
            background:brown;
            color:white;
            }
            
        </style>
```

```html
      
           
                <div class="Exp">Blog</div>
```

Like this
[Check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vGSo.png)

is it possible or not in a CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you want can be achieved by overlaying a circular `div` on the text with a small border at the bottom and unhiding it upon hover

```html
<style>
   .arc {
       display: none;
       position: absolute;
       width: 2em;
       height: 2em;
       border-radius: 50%;    /* make it circular */
       background-color: transparent;
       border-bottom: 3px solid brown;  /* the arc effect */
   }
   .exp {
       font-style: italic;
   }
   .wrapper:hover > .arc {
       display: block;
   }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arc"></div>
    <div class="exp">Blog</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I will edit it as per my requirements